# La base de datos sql server express 2012 es compatible con visual studio community 2017

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, visual-studio-2017

Tengo instalado en mi ordenador visual studio community 2017 y quiero hacer unas pruebas integrando algunos softwares que he estado desarrollando para unas actividades de la universidad donde estudio con una base de datos sql server express 2012, debido a que en mi ordenador no puedo instalar las versiones más modernas de sql server express (mi ordenador no tiene los recursos suficientes).

Por eso quisiera saber si sql server express 2012 es compatible con visual studio community 2017, o sea, si puedo conectar los proyectos que desarrollo en visual studio community 2017 con una base de datos sql server express 2012.

Comment: La respuesta es si. La versión de Visual Studio no tiene nada que ver con la versión de Sql Server con la que es compatible. Puedes trabajar incluso contra versiones tan antiguas como Sql Server 2000

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo

Answer (score 1):

Si desarrollas con VS2017 puedes acceder a tus proyectos de SQ Server 2012, pero ojo, tendrás que migrar algunas cosillas.

Por ejemplo, los proyectos SSIS no corren, tendrás que adaptarlos, es decir, por defecto 2017 te abrira el proyecto para conectar con 2016 /2017, tendrás que cambiar las conexiones.

Por ejemplo, yo tengo VS2015 y en otro ordenador VS2017 y accedo a servidores SQL Server 2000, 2003, 2008 y ahora 2016, pero los paquetes SSIS desarrollados he tenido que adaptarlos. Según requerimientos, otros programas han funcionado correctamente y alguna web, les he tenido que modificar la conexión en web.config y listo.

Si tienes el VS2017 instalado, pruébalo. No pierdes nada.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo